# Google Pie Chart. Slices too thin to read label

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Is there any way to format pie charts so that labels are readable when slices are very thin?
I've been looking for similar questions, but found nothing.

[image]

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: With default settings pie charts work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/af1sm95q/

Comment: you can [explode the smaller slices](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#exploding-a-slice) by using an `offset`...

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to post my code because it would be too much overhead. Anyway after much searching I found [this bug](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1170), and that was what caused the problem. The chart was drawn in a (Bootstrap) tab that was not visible at first.